# Running JAR on iPad/iPhone

Tags: java, ios

I have a JAR (java application), which I want to run on my iPad. Is that possible, How to do this? If possible through Appstore, (I know the process of Appstore and I have Apple Appstore account), please let me know is it possible to upload jar in Appstore and download from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, it's not possible to run jar file into iOS or upload to App store. but Oracle ADF Mobile uses a native container that runs applications on both iOS and Android from a single source base. One part of that native container is a headless/lightweight JVM, but it's definitely not a .jar file

http://java.dzone.com/articles/oracle-gets-java-running-ios
http://www.infoworld.com/t/java-programming/java-ios-just-keeps-getting-easier-204543

Comment: Although I suppose if you’re writing something CPU-intensive the efficiency loss in translation could be a concern

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible. Apple doesn't support Java. Apple uses Objective-C as its main language. If I'm not mistaken, Safari on iOS doesn't support Java too so you can't run applet on iOS too.

Comment: Safari does run JavaScript, which is a scripting language for websites. This is different from the compiled language Java, which can run on most operating systems on the PC, but is not supported by iOS.